# Rest Service URI Parameter types

Tags: rest

I'm having two rest methods as follows

1. /objects/(int:type)/(id:objectID)/(ver:version)
2. /objects/(int:type)/(id:objectID)/(str:version)

if i send the request as like the following URI
**http://localhost/REST/objects/0/123/latest** which of the above method gets called.

whether the 2 methods are same or different.

need to know what are all the parameter types available and what is the actual usage of each type.

And how the URI identifies the exact method

Answer (score 0):

That question is all about the server framework you are using and nothing about REST.  REST says nothing about URI structure, and certainly nothing about how URIs are mapped to handlers.